# The necessary energy required to ionize 1g of potasium in its fundamental state if the ionization energy is given

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms, atomic-structure, ionization-energy

> The energy of ionization of the potassium is $\pu{6.94\cdot 10^{-19} J/atom}.$ Find the necessary energy to ionize $\pu{1 g}$ of potasium that is found on its fundamental state.

**Attempt.** I really didn't want to overthink this so I tried with conversion factors:
$$\pu{6.94\cdot 10^{-19} J/atom} \cdot \frac{\pu{1 atom}}{\pu{1 molecule}} \cdot \frac{\pu{1 molecule}}{\pu{6.022\cdot 10^{23} moles}} \cdot \frac{\pu{1 mol} \ \text{of } \ce{K}}{\pu{39 g} \ \ce{K}}\\ \approx \pu{2.96775\cdot 10^{-44} J/g},$$
but that didn't give me the correct answer since the correct answer is $\pu{10.7 kJ/g}$. I'm clueless on what else to try. May anyone shine a light?

Comment: 6.022e23 mol of potassium is about 0.4% of the Earth mass.

Comment: [Houston, we have a "Problem" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/houston-we-have-a-problem-in-question-titles). Please use real titles. Note that the symbols of physical quantities are always upright (use `\pu{…}` macro). Your formula is meaningless. First, neither "atom" nor "molecule" nor "moles" (it's mol) nor "of K" (or symbol of any other chemical element and prepositions) are physical quantities or their proper symbols. Second, where is the derivation with symbolic algebra and the numeric answer you've obtained?

Comment: numeric answer is now edited, what do you mean by "symbolic algebra"?

Comment: @Acyex A symbolic algebraic expression typically implies writing an equation in generic form using *symbols* (not numbers or physical quantities) for all constants and variables. It's a universally recommended initial step of calculation prior to plugging in the numbers so that you tackle the problem conceptually and don't have to deal with units, dimensions and significant figures at the same time as you are figuring out the solution.

Comment: but what equation should I write about? There's no equation that I can know of related to this problem? I figured that since we have $\pu{J/atom}$ we could get $\pu{J/g}$ easily like that way. Can only think of the $\frac{1}{\lambda}=R(\frac{1}{n_1^2}-\frac{1}{n_2^2})$ formula? Since ionization means that $n_2\to \infty$ but don't know how that'll help

Comment: Don't overcomplicate. You know the energy per atom. You know the mass of potassium. How many potassium atoms are in 1g? Problem solved.

Comment: How on earth is that not showing enough effort? @matt_black isn't what you just mentioned the exact method I mentioned?

Comment: You have the correct method, but one of your ratios is flipped. $\pu{1 mol}$ is $\pu{6.022E23}$ molecules, you have that 1 molecule is $\pu{6.022E23 mol}.$ As a sanity check, even if you didn't know the right result, a gram should have more energy than a single atom, but your answer was smaller.

Comment: @Acyex The symbolic algebra is $\frac {E_\mathrm{I} \cdot N_\mathrm{A}}{M_\mathrm{K}}$.

Comment: @Acyex I didn't say "not enough effort" but the opposite. You overcomplicated the calculation and, as a result, made an error. The simple approach I suggested would have avoided the error by making the logic far more clear.

Comment: @matt_black oh no i wasn't referring to you, I was referring to the mod that deleted my question because apparently "it didn't show enough effort"... is there a way of like reporting or flagging the mod or something?

Comment: @Poutnik, Tyberius, matt_black yes it's solved now, thanks!

Comment: @Poutnik Again, neither the word "atom" nor chemical symbol of potassium are proper unit symbols, and should not be used in your expression. It's especially bad for potassium since now it looks like you are using kelvins for some reason. Also, the cross "×" should be used for the product of the numbers with the decimal sign denoted with a dot, not middle dot "·".

Comment: @Andselisk I just tweaked the OP expression. I was not going to give more effort to it. // BTW the central dot is put there by `\pu{}`

Comment: @Poutnik You should've used `E`, not `e`: `\pu{6.022E23}` $(\pu{6.022E23}),$ not `\pu{6.022e23}` $(\pu{6.022e23}).$ `mhchem` currently doesn't keep a track of what kind of decimal separator is used, unfortunately. Either way, thank you for going back and fixing things.

Comment: @andselisk $$\pu{6.94E-19 J} \cdot \frac{\pu{6.022E23} }{\pu{1 mol}} \cdot \frac {\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{39 g}}$$

Thanks, E vs e is the very new info for me, I was not aware it is case sensitive, nor what is the difference.